# Class variables MVC 2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I don't understand what I am doing wrong when setting my Class variables. For instance, when I call `setHelloWorld()`, `helloworld is: Hello World` is returned. Then when I call `getHelloWorld()`, `helloworld is:`, is returned. Why is `helloworld` behaving as an empty string after being set?

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    string helloworld;


    public string setHelloWorld(){
        helloworld = "Hello World";
        return "helloworld is: " + helloworld;
    }

    public string getHelloWorld() {
            return "helloworld is: " + helloworld;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of the controller is created per request, so no state is kept. It's part of the stateless nature of the web.

You can consider putting it in session state or http cache if you need it persisted for multiple requests.